# Factorization systems for vector bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces

Are there any well-known [factorization systems](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+factorization+system) for the category of vector bundles defined over topological spaces?

Comment: Shall we agree to rule out trivial examples like (Iso, All)?

Comment: Yes. I mean interesting ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, we consider [vector bundles over some base space $X$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vect%28X%29). The simplest case is if $X$ is a point. Then the category of vector bundles over $X$ is just the category of vector spaces (over whatever your base field $k$ is). This category [has exactly four weak factorization systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462305/categories-on-which-one-can-determine-all-model-structures): (isomorphisms, all), (injections, surjections), (surjections, injections), (all, isomorphisms). As an exercise, I encourage you to write down the weak factorization systems on other spaces, like two-point spaces. There are plenty!

If, rather than $Vect(X)$, you don't want to fix a base space, then you're taking the Grothendieck construction with respect to the functor that takes a space $X$ to $Vect(X)$. In this setting, there is a general technique for piecing together factorization systems from the base $Top$ and the fibers $Vect(X)$ to factorization systems on the total space. For more, check out [The Grothendieck construction for model categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1852) and [On bifibrations of model categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.10484). So, the answer is that there are plenty of factorization systems running around, both on the categories $Vect(X)$ and on $Top$, and on the Grothendieck construction.